# Extensions of finite groups and group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H \subset G$ is a subgroup and $K = G/H$ is the quotient group, so we have extension of groups 
$$
1 \to H \to G \to K \to 1.
$$
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, can one build group algebra $R[G]$ out of the group algebras $R[H]$ and $R[K]$?

In the trivial case $G\cong H \times K$ we have $R[G] \cong R[H] \otimes_R R[K]$, but how one can generalize this for non-trivial extensions?

Comment: Without knowing more about the maps $H\to G\to K$, no.  Example: $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]\not\cong\mathbb{R}[D_8]$ but both $Q_8$ and $D_8$ are central extensions of $V_4$ by $C_2$.

Comment: Sure, my question is how data of the extension translate into some data that can be used to "twist" the tensor product of group algebras. I don't assume that this can be done just by knowing $H$ and $K$.